# Avoid Code Duplication when unmarshalling similar json in go

Tags: json, go, struct

I'm struggling to come up with an elegant way of eliminating code duplication in Go. The `ReadImageDataJson` and `readJSON` functions are basically the same except they return different json formats.

```golang
package artworks

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
)

type Artworks struct {
    Artist         string `json:"artist"`
    Tags           string `json:"tags"`
    Id             string `json:"id"`
    Thumbnail      string `json:"thumbnail"`
    High_res_image string `json:"high_res_image"`
    Date_uploaded  string `json:"date_uploaded"`
    Url            string `json:"url"`
}

type ArtworksWithImageData struct {
    Artworks
    Imagedata string `json:"image_data"`
}

func ReadImageDataJson(filePath string) []ArtworksWithImageData {
    artworksList, error := ioutil.ReadFile(filePath)
    if error != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error when opening file: %v", error.Error())
    }
    var artworkData []ArtworksWithImageData
    error = json.Unmarshal(artworksList, &artworkData)
    if error != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error during unmarshal(): %v", error.Error())
    }
    return artworkData
}

func readJSON(filePath string) []Artworks {
    artworksList, error := ioutil.ReadFile(filePath)
    if error != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error when opening file: %v", error.Error())
    }
    var artworkData []Artworks
    error = json.Unmarshal(artworksList, &artworkData)
    if error != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error during unmarshal(): %v", error.Error())
    }
    return artworkData
}
```

I've got so far as writing this out:

```golang
func readJSON[T []Artworks | []ArtworksWithImageData](filePath string, jsonFormat T) T {
    artworksList, error := ioutil.ReadFile(filePath)
    if error != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error when opening file: %v", error.Error())
    }
    var artworkData T
    error = json.Unmarshal(artworksList, &artworkData)
    if error != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error during unmarshal(): %v", error.Error())
    }
    return artworkData
}
```

But I'm not sure it really works because when I call it, i.e. `readJson("myfile.json", []Artworks])` I get the error `[]Artworks (type) is not an expression`

Answer (score 1):

Actually think I just figured this out! Just had to add `omitempty` to the tag.

```golang
type Artworks struct {
    Artist         string `json:"artist"`
    Tags           string `json:"tags"`
    Id             string `json:"id"`
    Thumbnail      string `json:"thumbnail"`
    High_res_image string `json:"high_res_image"`
    Date_uploaded  string `json:"date_uploaded"`
    Url            string `json:"url"`
    Imagedata      string `json:"image_data,omitempty"`
}


func readJSON(filePath string) []Artworks {
    artworksList, error := ioutil.ReadFile(filePath)
    if error != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error when opening file: %v", error.Error())
    }
    var artworkData []Artworks
    error = json.Unmarshal(artworksList, &artworkData)
    if error != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error during unmarshal(): %v", error.Error())
    }
    return artworkData
}
```

I also figured out you can do this with generics if you're on go > 1.18:

```golang
func readJSONGeneric[T Artwork | ArtworkWithImageData](filePath string) (T, error) {
    var artworkData T
    artworksList, error := ioutil.ReadFile(filePath)
    if error != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error when opening file: %v", error.Error())
        return artworkData, error
    }
    error = json.Unmarshal(artworksList, &artworkData)
    if error != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error during unmarshal(): %v", error.Error())
        return artworkData, error

    }
    return artworkData, nil
}
```

Comment: The `,omitempty` option is used for _marshaling_, for unmarshaling it is ignored, it does nothing.